# How to make button to be act like checkbox?

Tags: angularjs

I have this row:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="list.showReview = list.showReview == $index ? -1 : $index; getValues(object.Id); "><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
```

I want it to be appeared like button but act like checkbox(when I click(check) the button `getValues` function have to be called `list.showReview` gets value,when i click again(uncheck)  the `getValues` not called but the `list.showReview` get the new value).

Any idea how can I implement this logic?I think this is best done with the help of checkbox.

Comment: Something like **[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/X533ioUncmVpLCFRjMaU?p=preview)** perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic in a controller.

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="showReview()"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.showReview = function () {
    if ($scope.list.showReview) {
       getValues($scope.object.Id)
    }
    $scope.list.showReview = !$scope.list.showReview;
}
```

I did not fully understand the logic you were looking for, but it might be along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

In shortest way:

```html
<button ng-click="checked = !checked;"> test </button> -- {{checked}}
```

-- {{checked}}